# functor as variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a deep compound term that I want to query.

assertion is

```
a(b(c(d))).
```

I try to query

```
?- a(B(c(d))).
```

Here B is a variable. It gives error. What is the way to query such structure?

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly a way to do it, but it is unnecessarily difficult.

What you have in the Prolog database is facts/rules. The `Name/Arity` of each fact and rule (called predicate indicators) is the *structure* of your data. The arguments are the *contents*.

Before continuing, consider some way of normalizing your data representation. It will make querying the data easier.

Instead of writing:

```
a(b(c(d))).
```

Could you write:

```
inside(a, b).
inside(b, c).
inside(c, d).
```

This would be one way to represent the nested structure that you have. To query it, you could write:

```
inside(a, X), inside(X, c), inside(c, d)
```

All the tricks from relational databases for representing nested, recursive structures in a flat table apply to Prolog, too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `=../2` aka. ["univ"](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) in a two-step process:

```
extract(a(Term),FunctorName) :-
  Term =.. [FunctorName|_FunctorArgs].
```

And so:

```
?- extract(a(b(c(d))),X).
X = b.
```

In SWI-Prolog, there are several non-standard predicates to cover the extra cases of arity-0 compound terms and dicts. Take a look at [this note](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/swipl_notes/about_term_analysis_and_construction)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for valuable answers. It seems I am trying to use prolog in a way it is not meant to be used.

For example say that I want to describe the structure of my data. Customer data has createdtime attribute.

```
storedobject(customer).

has(customer, 
  field(createdtime(
    type (datetime (max('01013000'), min('01011000'))))
  )
).
```

if I make it flat and global createdtime assertion that will cause confusion because other storedobjects/tables also have createdtime with different max min. And createdtime can be used in different context in different form. So I was hoping the structure above helping me to specify which createdtime I am talking about, that is field on the customer object.

In the above form I was hoping to query like this to get all datetime fields.

```
?- has( TableName, field ( FieldName ( datetime (max(Max),min(Min))
```

Comment: It is best to post this "answer" as a new question to get appropriate feedback. But the Prolog database behaves like an relational database w/o the table declarations, where you say in SQL "SELECT FROM customer VALUES customerid, max_datetime, min_datetime". It's indeed tables.

Comment: first, there must not be any whitespace between functor name and opening brace, otherwise it is invalid term in Prolog. when you fix this, try `has(TableName,X),X=field(Y),Y=..[FieldName | R].` as a starting point.

Comment: You are very obviously still seeing hierarchical data, more in the spirit of an object-oriented model of your data. You have to instead thing about it in terms of relations. This is what will allow you to put your data in flat tables and query it with Prolog. If you read a bit on relational database design, you might get ideas and be able to ask more specific questions that will help you with more useful answers.